# Como exibir o número da linha de um método em Java?

Tags: java, método

Bom dia ,

Estou usando o AST , assim consegui acessar os métodos, atributos e obter se ele é public ou private, dentre outras coisa.

Como faço para exibir o número da linha de determinado atributo ou método?
Exemplo:

```
int privado = Modifier.ModifierKeyword.PRIVATE_KEYWORD.toFlagValue();

public Teste (ICompilationUnit unit) throws JavaModelException, MalformedTreeException, BadLocationException {
    Document documento = new Document(unit.getSource());
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(unit);
    CompilationUnit compUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    compUnit.recordModifications();
    AST ast = compUnit.getAST();

    Visitor visitor = new Visitor();
    compUnit.accept(visitor);


    for (FieldDeclaration f : type.getFields()) {
        int tipo = f.getModifiers();                                                
        if ((tipo & publico) == publico) {
            mensagem.add(" \n O ATRIBUTO "+f.fragments().toString()+" é public \n");

        }       

    }
}
```

Queria informar em ali em : O atributo teste é publico na **Linha x**.

Answer (score 0):

> Tente este código:

```java
    System.out.println("Número da linha #" + 
    new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
```